# How to get current date in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift3, nstimezone

I want to get current date and time zone of user in Swift 3. I tried in Swift 2.2 following code :

```
static var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation!}
```

Comment: are you want date and timezone separate ?  sample code just return timezone.

Comment: yes i want date and timezone separately. and Thanks Nirav D solution work for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For getting `abbreviation` from `NSTimeZone`.

```
static var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return  NSTimeZone.local.abbreviation(for: Date())! }
```

For getting current `Date`.

```
let currentDate = Date()
```